# What is the most efficient (quickest) way to return (a copy of) a row of a two-dimensional list with a given id in Python?

Tags: python

What is the most efficient (quickest) way to return (a copy of) a row of a two-dimensional list with a given id in Python? The first element of each row is an ID (string). My function needs to search two-dimensional list for the row with the matching ID and return a copy of that row. If there is no match, it should return None.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a dictionary instead of a nested list.

Comment: Ok, but the requirement is that I use a list

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: As @flakes says, a `dict`; using the `.get()` function, which returns `None` if the key is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it only once, iterating over the list and checking the first element would be the best.

If you can pre-process the table, I suggest converting into a dictionary first:

`d = {row[0]: row for row in lst}`

and then searching:

`d.get(id)`

Slow list iteration (If you can't use a dict, as you specified in comments section):

```
for row in lst:
    if row[0] == id:
        break
else:
    row = None
```

Comment: Today I learned you can put an `else` on a `for` loop. Neat

Comment: Thanks you very much @flakes. I think I will use the dictionary way. performance was important too for me. Great answer!

Comment: @JMushiana No problem! You should upvote Bharel's answer as well to award them more for the detailed answer!

Comment: Just realized that with the recent speed optimizations, the optimized solution was exactly the same speed as the non-optimized and simpler. Removed the harder dict creation.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this without changing the model you will need to do an `O(n)` search, but I highly question opting for this choice if you really want to optimize for speed as you mention in the description:

```
import copy


def find_element(data, id):
    for entry in data:
        if entry[0] == id:
            return copy.copy(entry)
    return None
```

Comment: Lists have a `.copy()`. I omitted it cause I'm not sure if he actually needs a copy :shrug:

Comment: @Bharel Yeah, just a preference. Works on more possible iterable types like tuples. Copy was in the description so I added it.